# How can I specify the -highentropyva C# compiler option in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Here is the image for .NET Core web application properties. I want to enable **HIGHENTROPYVA** in this:

[image]

Comment: Posting a link to something that *doesn't* contain or explain what you want doesn't help anyone. Your actual question seems to be how to specify C# compiler options in Visual Studio

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570858/passing-highentropyva-to-csc-compiler-from-msbuild-command-line-or-project-fil

Comment: Here is the complete discription.
As a developer, I need to enable /HIGHENTROPYVA (Support 64-Bit ASLR) and /LARGEADDRESSAWARE (Handle Large Addresses) switches if they are not enabled for 64-bit version of .Net Applications (CTI Server, Presence Server, Web Admin, Database Component and CUAC Standard). I then need to verify by running necessary tests to ensure that these switches are in action for application when it is run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing /highentropyva- to CSC compiler from MSBuild command-line or project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570858/passing-highentropyva-to-csc-compiler-from-msbuild-command-line-or-project-fil)